# Replace everything except uppercase letters with the first parameter given (with sed)

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
sed "s/[a-z]/$1/g" <old.txt>new.txt 
echo "done"
```

This only replaces lowercase letters with the first parameter given. I want to replace everything except uppercase letters.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed "s/[^[:upper:]]/$1/g"
```

Would replace all characters that are not considered as an upper-case letter in your locale with the content of `$1` (provided `$1` doesn't contain `&`, backslash or slash or newline characters).

Note that it would not replace bytes that are not part of valid characters. It will also happily convert combining characters. For instance, `É` is an upper-case character. If written as the U+00C9 character, it will be left alone, but if written as `E` followed by the combining acute accent character (U+0301), that will be changed to `E$1`.